# R function with argument as part of new variable

Tags: r, function

I want to create a function to sum two columns together, in which one word connects two columns and there are three sets. I want to pass that word as the only argument, and add a new column with that same name. Something like this.

```
the_first_x <- c(0,0,10,0)
the_second_x <- c(10,0,10,0)
the_first_y <- c(0,5,5,5)
the_second_y <- c(5,5,0,0)

df <- data.frame(the_first_x,
                 the_second_x,
                 the_first_y,
                 the_second_y)

summing <- function(letter){
  df$letter <- the_first_letter + the_second_letter
}
```

Such that using the following adds a column with that letter as a name and that sum as its rows

```
summing(x)
summing(y)
```

By doing it like this, the `letter` argument is not recognised, and using something like `paste()` makes that the argument is surrounded by parentheses and also not recognised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a better approach.
(one should avoid using `<<-` where possible)

```
summing <- function(data, letter, pattern = paste0(letter,"$")){
    data[[letter]] <- rowSums(data[,grepl(pattern,names(data),)], na.rm = T)
    return(data)
}
```

This function is especially handy when working with a pipe:

```
library(magrittr)
df %>% summing("x") %>% summing("y")

#  the_first_x the_second_x the_first_y the_second_y  x  y
#1           0           10           0            5 10  5
#2           0            0           5            5  0 10
#3          10           10           5            0 20  5
#4           0            0           5            0  0  5
```

---

Of course, you can use it without a pipe:

```
ans <- summing(df, "x")
summing(ans, "y")
```

---

The `pattern` argument takes **regular expression**. With that, it's very general and specific to which columns you want to add.

Comment: Thanks, that works! It also works without the pattern:

`summing <- function(data, letter){
  data[[letter]] <- rowSums(data[,grepl(letter,names(data),)], na.rm = T)
  return(data)
}`

Comment: sure it does with this example. But consider a column-name `xbox`. You would match that as well when you type `"x"` and therefore sum it also. The regex pattern assures you that you match only the cols you intend to add. Be as specific in the pattern as possible.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against using (1) `<<-` and (2) `deparse(substitute(...))`.
Concerning (1), this is advice taken from [What is the difference between assign() and <<- in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785290/what-is-the-difference-between-assign-and-in-r) on what *not* to use `<<-` for (addition in bracket is mine):

> The Evil and Wrong use [of `<<-`] is to modify variables in the global environment.

Here is a `tidyverse` option using some `rlang` syntax:

```
library(tidyverse)
my_sum <- function(df, x) {
    x <- enquo(x)
    col <- names(df)[str_detect(names(df), quo_name(x))]
    df %>% mutate(!!x := !!sym(col[1]) + !!sym(col[2]))
}
df %>% my_sum(x)
#  the_first_x the_second_x the_first_y the_second_y  x
#1           0           10           0            5 10
#2           0            0           5            5  0
#3          10           10           5            0 20
#4           0            0           5            0  0

df %>% my_sum(y)
#  the_first_x the_second_x the_first_y the_second_y  y
#1           0           10           0            5  5
#2           0            0           5            5 10
#3          10           10           5            0  5
#4           0            0           5            0  5
```

We can nicely chain multiple `my_sum` calls:

```
df %>% my_sum(x) %>% my_sum(y)
#  the_first_x the_second_x the_first_y the_second_y  x  y
#1           0           10           0            5 10  5
#2           0            0           5            5  0 10
#3          10           10           5            0 20  5
#4           0            0           5            0  0  5
```

Comment: whats wrong about `deparse(substitute(...))`. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @AndreElrico There are some pitfalls that may lead to unexpected behaviour when using `deparse(substitute(...))`. At least they really confused me in the past. Details and examples can be found in [Pier Lorenzo Paracchini's *Non-Standard Evaluation in R*](https://rpubs.com/pparacch/280365), [Hadley Wickham's *Non-standard evaluation*](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lazyeval/vignettes/lazyeval.html), and the SO post [Non standard evaluation in Hadley's advanced R book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336780/non-standard-evaluation-in-hadleys-advanced-r-book).

Comment: You're very welcome @AndreElrico. Those examples from the linked SO post still do my head in...;-)